# Difference of between List and copyed MutableList

Tags: android, kotlin

I copyed List type variable to new one of MutableList type,

then updated value of new one's item.

But origin variable was updated too.

Are these point to same address?

Why?

```
var foodList = listOf(
    FoodModel("curry", 2000)
    FoodModel("rice", 1000)
)


// copyed foodList to new variable MutableList<FoodModel> type
val tempList = foodList as MutableList<FoodModel>

Log.e("weird", tempList[position].name+" "+tempList[position].price)
Log.e("weird", foodList[position].name+" "+foodList[position].price)
//E/weird: rice 1000
//E/weird: rice 1000


tempList[position] = FoodModel(nameEdit.text.toString(), priceEdit.text.toString().toInt())


Log.e("weird", tempList[position].name+" "+tempList[position].price)
Log.e("weird", foodList[position].name+" "+foodList[position].price)
//E/weird: rice 3333
//E/weird: rice 3333
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are these point to same address?

Yes, because `foodList as MutableList<FoodModel>` is not copying, it is type casting and it can lead to a `ClassCastException` or `UnsupportedOperationException`.  To copy a list use `toMutableList()`

```
val tempList = foodList.toMutableList()
```

Answer (score -1):

FoodModel is reference type, so your `foodList` is a list of references. When you copy it, you get a new list with old references to models, so when you modify value of reference in new list it is reflected to the previous list.

You can solve this by creating a deep copy of the list. For example:

```kotlin
data class FoodModel(val str: String, val int: Int)
foodList.mapTo(mutableListOf(), FoodModel::copy)
```

Comment: `as` is type casting, deep copying is not necessary in this case